# Should we mock a static function in unit testing which don't have further external dependencies(like a function which just do c# calculation)?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

One of my colleagues suggested & also in some forums I found people talking that it's fine if we skip to mock a static function call if that function is not making any server or db calls. But as per theory of Unit testing we should be testing a unit of code only, any external calls out of that class should be mocked.

I am confused as if how the calling class knows that if that static function call is having db call or it's a c# calculation? The mocking should be done independent of consideration that the static function is making call to db or not.

Comment: Can you even mock static methods?

Comment: It depends on ... there is no point in mocking *Enum.GetValues* but *Console.Write* is maybe be a design failure

Comment: @SirRufo Well the Static function is just manually created function in Project it's not any inbuilt library function. The function contains some C# dictionary manipulations only.

Comment: Do you need to be able to control the  results of making the call directly in your test, or would you always be basically recreating the actual behavior? If it's the latter, I wouldn't bother using a fake of any description - just like I wouldn't try to fake out the results of `string.Substring` etc.

Comment: @DaisyShipton as I mentioned in previous reply this static function is our created utility function not any inbuilt function like YearConverter.YearToText.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really answer my question. I was giving `string.Substring` as an example of something you wouldn't want to fake out, *because you'd always want it to behave the way it does anyway*. The fact that it's provided by the system is irrelevant. (By contrast, `DateTime.UtcNow` is provided by the system but still *definitely* worth isolating in tests via a clock abstraction, so that you can test how your code behaves on different dates etc.)